# How to covert the 'Real World Haskell' list data type to using Maybe?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I've been studying 'Real World Haskell' and I'm stuck on working out how to use Maybe. I wrote this data type and corresponding function from Chapter 3. The book suggests trying to convert it to use Maybe and get rid of the Nil type. I've been playing around with this but I can't work out how to do it. I've tried adding maybe in different places, but I'm really just guessing rather than knowing how to do it.

```
data List a = List a (List a)
            | Nil
            deriving (Show)

toList :: List a -> [a]
toList (List a Nil) = a:[]
toList (List a as)  = a:(toList as)
```

Comment: Can't remember such an exercise, but there is an exercise to convert a `Tree` to use `Maybe`.

Comment: Yes you're right. I wanted to see if I could do the same thing for the list example too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at this:

```
data List a              data Maybe a
    = List a (List a)        = Just a
    | Nil                    | Nothing
```

When you write it this way, the parallel looks pretty clear -- we just need to put some extra data in the `Just` side! To put "extra" data, we can use a tuple. The only other wrinkle is that we *must* name a constructor.

```
data List' a = List' (Maybe (a, List' a {- here's the extra bit -}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should the method signature still be toList :: (List a) -> [a] ?

Comment: @MichaelBarton I suppose what exercises you want to tackle is pretty much up to you. Does that sound like a fun thing to try to write? If so, I say go for it!

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, if wanted to modify my function above to use use the maybe list what should the type signature be?

Comment: @MichaelBarton I think the signature you proposed is fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
data List a = List a (Maybe (List a))
```

would do it.  You'd have `List 1 (Just (List 2 Nothing))` to represent `[1, 2]`.  I don't know if it's the most elegant or the easiest to use, though.

Comment: I think you want the `Maybe` to cover more stuff -- this type has no empty lists!